# Linking 32-bit library to 64-bit program

Tags: linux, 64-bit, 32-bit, 32bit-64bit

I have a 32-bit .so binary-only library and I have to generate 64-bit program that uses it.
Is there a way to wrap or convert it, so it can be used with 64-bit program?

Comment: I was going to suggest recompiling the library code targetting 64bit, but get the impression you do not have the source to it...I am doubtful if a 64bit code can 'thunk' across to 32bit..maybe it can under linux's gcc? But then again this 'thunking' was a feature of Win95 (Remember that?) 32bit code calling 16bit code...have you tried linking the 64bit code referencing the 32bit dynamic library (.so) and running it?

Comment: There is no "thunking" equivelent in any of the modern 64bit operating systems.  This won't work.

Comment: Never tried that, but it might be possible by decompiling the library to c code, and then you might need to make some modifications. then compile it to 64bit...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

No.  You can't directly link to 32bit code inside of a 64bit program.

The best option is to compile a 32bit (standalone) program that can [run on your 64bit platform (using ia32)](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/Running_32-bit_Applications_on_64-bit_Debian_GNU/Linux), and then use a form of inter-process communication to communicate to it from your 64bit program.

Comment: @Reed: Then how did Win95 manage the transition from 32bit code calling 16bit a la 'thunking' ? Was that at the assembler level to change around the stack pointer and registers?

Comment: The OS handled this explicitly, but there is nothing that allows this in Linux or modern 64bit Windows operating systems, so you have to use a workaround like I posted.

Comment: @Reed: what IPC mechanism would you recommend? I think that shared memory should be reasonable faster then e.g. pipes or Unix Doman Sockets.

Comment: Well that's a shame.  Thunking was a very useful technique and allowed you to be able to call 16bit dll's from 32bit apps, or in one case that I had I needed to call a 32bit dll from a 16bit app.  It's unfortuante that the modern OS's don't provide that capability for 32/64bit code.  I guess there is a reason for it... maybe complexity.

Comment: x86_64 use a different calling convention than x86, as well as different number of regiters (double) makes it harder to link the 2 architectures all together

Answer (score 5):

For an example of using IPC to run 32-bit plugins from 64-bit code, look at the open source [NSPluginWrapper](http://nspluginwrapper.org/).

Answer (score 4):

It is possible, but not without some serious magic behind the scenes and you will not like the answer. Either emulate a 32 bit CPU (no I am not kidding) or switch the main process back to 32 bit. Emulating may be slow though.

[This is a proof of concept](http://emumiga.com) of the technique.

Then keep a table of *every* memory access to and from the 32 bit library and keep them in sync. It is very hard to get to a theoretical completeness, but something workable should be pretty easy, but very tedious.

In most cases, I believe two processes and then IPC between the two may actually be easiest, as suggested othwerwise.