# Possible to link 64 bit library to 32 bit application?

Tags: 32bit-64bit

Actually I want to link 64 bit library to my 32 bit application.
I want to use a library which works faster under 64 bits under some circumstances. But i have to link that library to my 32 bit application . Is it possible or not ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can 32 bit and 64 bit work together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15971830/can-32-bit-and-64-bit-work-together)

Comment: Some rare architectures may support *thunking* between 32 and 64-bit apps, but most don't. And you can't link mixed code in any architectures. [Use 32bit shared library from 64bit application?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10039401/995714), [Linking 32-bit library to 64-bit program](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1943681/995714), [Ways to access a 32bit DLL from a 64bit exe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2804818/995714), [Can 32-bit and 64-bit code be mixed? (duplicate)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8862366/995714)

Comment: [Can a 64 bit EXE link against 32-bit DLLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1116265/995714), [Can 32-bit and 64-bit code be mixed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8862366/995714)

Answer (score 0):

In a word, no. The only way to get compiled 64bit code talking to compiled 32bit code is via some form of IPC (e.g. pipe, named pipe, or network connection). That may well introduce performance bottlenecks of its own, so probably isn't worth the bother.

Answer (score 0):

It is not easy as @robthebloke mentioned. But NVIDIA RTX Remix Runtime does it somehow, making older 32bit games running on 64-bit vulkan driver (bypassing 2-4GB virtual memory limit).