# Include 32-bit library into an existing 64-bit application

Tags: qt, gcc, 32bit-64bit

I have a existing 64-bit Qt Linux project (C/C++), now I wanted to add additional hardware. Unfortunately the hardware vendor provides a SDK with 32-bit binary-only C .so.

Just including the library leads to an error like this:

```
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: skipping incompatible /home/SDK/lib when searching for -example
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -example
```

Is there any way to include this library into my existing project?

I found [Mixing 32 and 64-bit Libraries in Linux (gcc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19391501/mixing-32-and-64-bit-libraries-in-linux-gcc), but maybe there are some changes as it's already 7 years old.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why this question got -1? I am having the same problem with vendor libs. The person who gave -1 could at least point some directions?

Answer (score 2):

The x86 and amd64 ABIs are completely different on Linux, so you can't call 32-bit libraries from 64-bit code directly. That said, you can achieve your objective by creating a separate 32-bit program that proxies calls into the library and exposes them via REST, WSDL, Protobuf, or your favorite way of doing IPCs, and then making those calls from the 64-bit process.

Comment: I think this should work in general, unfortunately I'm not able to run a 32-bit process on my machine as it is more like an embedded linux with 64-bit support only.

Comment: You'll need to install 32-bit versions of ld.so, libc, plus all of the shared libraries that your 32-bit library depends on.